# Can't access OS selection screen or Windows files form Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows, uefi

I have installed Ubuntu 15.10 and Windows 10 successfully on my laptop. Earlier I was given a choice to choose which OS to load via gnu grub. I remember I accidently clicked some buttons (then it went to maybe edit gnu grub or etc., I was trying to swap Windows and Ubuntu's position). Now I no longer can choose which OS to load (it boots directly to Windows), but I found a workaround: When the laptop starts I keep pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then I press <kbd>F9</kbd>, then I get a choice again but maybe in some BIOS style. Also I can't access Windows files, I get this error (maybe because I stopped Windows' booting in between):

```
Unable to access “Windows”

Error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/aditya/Windows: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda4" "/media/aditya/Windows"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Disabling fast boot from power options in windows again allowed to access windows files from ubuntu.
- I booted into boot setting (<kbd>F10</kbd>) and then changed UEFI boot order using <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>F6</kbd>. First entry was some boot manager or something which had two entries windows loader or something and ubuntu, I switched their order.

Answer (score 2):

First you can fix the boot problem , you must update the grub by typing:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and you will have the boot options again.

Second for the mount error you simply start windows and then you "restart" it (so windows is fully shut down ) and on directly boot on Ubuntu when the grub shows up.

Answer (score 2):

I am also facing the same problem and every time I have to keep pressing `F9` to get the boot loader option.

But I can still tell you a method to access the Windows files. Just follow the following steps.

```
Go to Control Panel.
Click Power Options.
Click Choose what the power buttons do.
Click Change settings that are currently unavailable.
Scroll down to Shutdown settings and uncheck Turn on fast startup.
Click Save changes.
```

See the image for more details

[image: See the image for more details.]

Comment: see my answer, above

Comment: I just explained it in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

I too had the same issue a couple of days ago (had to access them through esc + F9 in my HP Notebook), where grub window doesn't show up and directly boots to windows 10, in my dual boot alongside ubuntu 16.04. Recently i tried a solution i found online and followed the step,and it did work for me. The issue was with the boot order in Boot Manager. I hope this can fix your issue. So here is the link:
http://linuxbsdos.com/2016/11/05/make-grub-the-default-boot-manager-on-an-hp-250-g5/

This issue of  "missing" grub window was due to the problem in the placement order of OS in the boot manager. Previously, Windows 10 was on the top of the list. Hence it directly booted Windows 10. Now changing the order (by making Ubuntu on the top of the list) will let us access grub window. ( Note: Here fn key is not used whenever Fuctional keys are used)

Here i've mentioned the steps i followed:
1.  Press esc key (for HP Notebook ) for getting the Boot menu .
 
 2.  From the options listed (F1-System Information, F2-System Diagnostics, F9-Boot Device Options, F10-Bios Setup, F11-System Recovery) press F10 for Bios Setup.
3.  From the screen you obtain, navigate to "System Configuration" using arrow keys and from there move down to "UEFI Boot Order". Press Enter key to access sub-options from it. 
4. Inside the sub-option, select "OS Boot Manager"   and press Enter key to reveal the options inside it ( in my case, the order inside the option was  Windows 10 ,then GRUB)
5. Press F5/F6 key to change the order and make GRUB on top of the list.
 
6. After changing the order, press F10 to save the changes and exit.
 
  Now its good to go! From now on, you may find GRUB window each time you switch on the computer, instead of directly booting to Windows. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu;  Glad you can propose a working solution.  Could you improve your answer by adding in a nutshell the main steps contained in the link you refer to.  this way, your answer remains valid even if the link disappers.

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen: Thank you for your feedback.  : )